# Whats the right way to encode an umlaut in a dataURI

Tags: javascript, diacritics, data-uri

I  have a small script that let the user save a CSV file using dataURI. Unfortunately there are some problems with german umlauts, so `Käufe` will become `KÃ¤ufe`. The href with the dataURI is created like this:

```
'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvString)
```

Comment: Aside: you know that the [data Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(v=vs.85).aspx) is not supported by IE: _Data URIs cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or to populate frame or iframe elements._?

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely not a problem of the encoding in the URL, but of whoever is interpreting that data later not understanding that it's encoded in UTF-8 and interpreting it in Latin-1 instead. There is no "right way" to encode non-ASCII characters in a URL. URLs can only consist of a subset of ASCII characters, period. For anything else there's the percent encoding method to encode arbitrary bytes to the `%xx` format. What encoding those bytes represent is entirely up to you and is entirely up to the recipient to interpret in the correct encoding.